# Find similar list value inside dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to find a match from my list to a list in a dictionary value

For example, the dictionary contains

```
dict = {"test1": [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        "test2": [2, 2, 3, 4], 
        "test3": [1, 2, 4, 5], 
        "test4": [6, 2, 3, 4], 
        "test5": [7, 2, 3, 4]}
```

and the data I need to find matches for if

```
answer = [6,2,3,4]
```

I am trying to pull any test where the first value of the answer input must be different and the rest the same so for example

```
[(this is different), 2,3,4]
```

then at the end I want `test1`, `test2`, and `test5` to be recorded.

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that didn't produce your desired output?

Comment: "***so at the end I want test1, test2, and test 5 to be recorded.***" - What do you mean by "to be recorded"? It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the items of the dict and compare the slices of the sub-lists to the slice of the list you want to check against:

```
d = {'test1':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'test2':[2, 2, 3, 4], 'test3':[1,2,4,5], 'test4':[6,2,3,4], 'test5':[7, 2, 3,4]}
def check(d, l):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v != l and v[1:] == l[1:]:
            yield k
print(list(check(d, [6, 2, 3, 4])))
```

This outputs:

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid dictionary with string keys, using a list comprehension can filter out the unwanted keys as follows:

```
>>> d = {
...     "test1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
...     "test2": [2, 2, 3, 4],
...     "test3": [1, 2, 4, 5],
...     "test4": [6, 2, 3, 4],
...     "test5": [7, 2, 3, 4]
... }
>>> answer = [6, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [k for k, v in d.items() if v[0] != answer[0] and v[1:] == answer[1:]]
['test1', 'test2', 'test5']
```

Note that `dict = ...` overwrites a builtin function `dict`, which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
dict_a = { 
    'test 1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'test 2': [2, 2, 3, 4], 'test 3': [1, 2, 4, 5], 
    'test 4': [6, 2, 3, 4], 'test 5': [7, 2, 3, 4]
}

answer = [6, 2, 3, 4]

for i in dict_a:
    if answer[0] != dict_a[i][0]:
        if answer[1:4] == dict_a[i][1:4]:
            print(dict_a[i])
```

**Store Output**

```
answer = [6, 2, 3, 4]
store = {}

for i in dict_a:
    if answer[0] != dict_a[i][0]:
        if answer[1:4] == dict_a[i][1:4]:
            store[i] = dict_a[i]

for k in store:
    print(f"{k}: {store[k]}")
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 list_dict.py 
> [1, 2, 3, 4]
> [2, 2, 3, 4]
> [7, 2, 3, 4]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are couple of issues with your code. 
First of, since dict is a keyword, it should be avoided as a variable name. 
Secondly, variables test1, test2 etc are not defined. In this case, it is better to use 'test1','test2' etc

Anyways, see the answer below.

```
            dic = {'test1':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'test2':[2, 2, 3, 4], 'test3':[1,2,4,5], 
                'test4':[6,2,3,4], 'test5':[7, 2, 3,4]}


            toMatch = [6,2,3,4]

            matching = []
            for (key, value) in dic.items():
                if((value[1:]==toMatch[1:])&(value[0]!=toMatch[0])):
                    print(key,value)
                    matching.append(key)

            print('Matching keys are:', matching)
```

Answer is:

```
test1 [1, 2, 3, 4]
test2 [2, 2, 3, 4]
test5 [7, 2, 3, 4]
Matching keys are: ['test1', 'test2', 'test5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is the kind of thing you should consider abstracting into a function.

```
def match_records(a, b):
    return a[-3:] == b[-3:] and a[0] != b[0]

results = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if match_records(answers, v)}
```

Comment: this will even return test 4 but that should not be the case. Your condition is insufficient. you should include a condition to check that the first numbers should not be the same

Comment: @Onyambu oh I missed that condition.